# How to simply use facebook login for my app without using the SDKs?

Tags: facebook, curl, oauth, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

Is there a simple flow (hello world) for a user to login using facebook?

Found [documentation on Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow), but is too full of text and details that I don't see the main flow.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow) (showing only the minimal data needed to make it work):

1. Create a facebook app.
2. Simulate the user clicking on the following authentication URL to allow the app to access the user's data: `https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=<app id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost/`
3. Click `ok/accept/whatever` to authorize access.
4. You get redirected by facebook to a URL of the following: `http://localhost/?code=<code>`
5. Take the code and invoke the following: `curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost&client_secret=<app secret>&code=<code>'`
6. You get a result like the following: `{"access_token":"<access token>","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5183924}`
7. You can then use the access token to call API related to the user that gave the permissions to your app. Example: `curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=<access token>'`
8. Example response: `{"name":"Alik Elzin","id":"<app related user id>"}`

* Remember to add `http://localhost/` to the app's `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` - under app settings.

Comment: I know it's strange I answered my own question. It's for the public+private good :) [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Note that the app secret should never be stored anywhere in your app. Your server-side component should initiate steps 5-6 and return the access token back to your app.

Comment: If you do it this way, would facebook open in the app if they have it installed? Or would it be in a Secure Web View prompting them for their facebook username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this documentation from Facebook? It's pretty short to read through: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow